# image is not displaying in my phone while debug using xamarin form

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

```
        <Image Source="https://images2.minutemediacdn.com/image/upload/c_crop,h_842,w_1500,x_0,y_88/f_auto,q_auto,w_1100/v1555006794/shape/mentalfloss/istock-522735736.jpg" />
```

This is code not displaying the image in an andriod device.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms Image's UriImageSource is known to misbehave and hence the community unanimously prefers using FFImageLoading instead. I can show you how if you are interested.

Comment: Does the image appear in the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an issue reported](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7684) in `Xamarin.forms` version `4.2.0.778463` early. I just did a test and  I can confirm that it has been fixed in the latest `Xamarin.forms` version `4.2.0.848062`.

So the **solution** is update your `Xamarin.forms` version to the latest `4.2.0.848062`.

**Note**: After updating the `Xamarin.forms` version, you have to just uninstall the app and delete the `obj/bin` folder both under `Xamrin.forms` project and `Xamarin.Android` project. Then clean and rebuild again.

Refer to [this comment](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7751#issuecomment-537156355):

> there's a bug where if it was retrieved wrong in the previous version
>   it'll return the wrong cached version in the new one

[image: screenshou]

Comment: image is not diplaying

Comment: @AbiramiJothi Please make sure you have deleted the obj/bin folder and uninstall the app after update the xamarin.forms version. Then clean and rebuild again otherwise it will load a previous cache image which would case the image does not display. Did you do these steps?  I can share your my test sample if you need.

Comment: @AbiramiJothi Please check the sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/test-image).

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning NU1605 Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Forms from 4.2.0.848062 to 4.2.0.709249. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 AppImg.Android -> AppImg -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.2.0.848062) 
 AppImg.Android -> Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.2.0.709249) AppImg.Android

Comment: @AbiramiJothi That means you did not update the Xamarin.forms to  4.2.0.848062 successfully! Please uninstall other nuget packages which has conflict with  Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.848062. After installing Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.848062 successfully, install those packages back again.

Comment: what if I want to display the local image

Comment: @AbiramiJothi Check the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images), make sure you place the image in the right place under each project.